# Vue.js + Apache , how to write redirect rules for multiple entries?

Tags: apache, vue.js, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a vue.js app which consists of 2 entry points `(2 SPA's)`. one of them is `index.html`, which serves the client website and the other is for the platform (`platform.html`)

Following the Vue CLI documentation, I am using the following in my `.htacess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

this only works if I only have index.html and when I type in `myUrl.com/platform` it doesn't change to the platform.
I have tried the following and can't make it work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^platform(.*)$ platform.html [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are the URLs for the two platforms? Is that `/platform/<something>` or `/platform<something>` (as could be implied by your question)?

Comment: @MrWhite it's like this `/platform/<subroute>`

Comment: In that case, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ would be better as `^platform($|/)`, rather than simply `^platform` to avoid potentially matching too much. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any URL prefixed with `platform` should be sent to `platform.html` and everything else to `index.html` then you could do something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Optimisation - prevent rewritten requests for the front-controller being reprocessed
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^platform\.html$ - [L]

# Prevent static resources being routed through the app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Any URLs that start "/platform" (whole path segment only) are sent to "/platform.html"
RewriteRule ^platform($|/) platform.html [L]

# All other URLs are sent to "/index.html"
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrappers, unless these directives are *optional* (they are not). (It doesn't make sense to nest these wrappers in this way.) See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack for more discussion on this: [Is Checking For mod_write Really Necessary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary)

Note that requests for the document root are not actually rewritten by the directives above, but are instead sent to `index.html` by the `DirectoryIndex` directive - this is often already configured on the server, so the directive may not be required here.

**UPDATE:** Since your URLs are like `/platform/<subroute>`, rather than `/platform<something>`, the regex in the above rule would be better as `^platform($|/)`, rather than simply `^platform`, in order to match the whole path segment only and to avoid potentially matching too much, such as `/platformsomething`. (I've updated the code above.)

`^platform($|/)` matches `platform` or `platform/something`, but not `platformsomething`.